# Java: functional chaining of getters or zero args methods

Tags: java, functional-interface

I want to create `Comparator` based on `Enum.name()` which is inside a bean class:

```
List.of(new JobRsp(Job.MY), new JobRsp(Job.OUR), new JobRsp(Job.YOUR)).stream()
    .sorted(__ -> __.getJob().name());
```

If I only needed `Enum.order()` I could write `sorted(Job::getJob)`.

Is it possible co compose zero args methods in functional style in Java? Something like:

```
FuncUtils.compose(Job::getJob, Enum::name)
```

Or probably even longer:

```
.sort(FuncUtils.chainGetters(ObjA::getB, ObjB::getC, ObjC::getD, ObjD::getE))
```

Imaginary `chainGetters` might check for `null`s.

I understand that Java doesn't allow variadic generics so there should be `chainGetters` for each argument arity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the default `andThen` method in `Function` interface that lets you chain functions.

Unfortunately there is no "clean" way to achieve the result, because to call a default method on a method reference you need to assign it, or cast it.

For example:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Function<Job, Enum> getJob = Job::getJob;
...
   .sorted(comparing(getJob.andThen(Enum::name)))
```

Or:

```
   .sorted(comparing( ((Function<Job, Enum>) Job::getJob).andThen(Enum::name) ))
```

So, it's cleaner to use a lambda expression using `Comparator.comparing` to create the comparator:

```
...
   .sorted(comparing(j -> j.getJob().name()))
```

The `compose` utility method that you suggest could be also implemented with:

```
public static <A, B, C>  Function<A, C> compose(Function<A, B> first, Function<B, C> second) {
    return first.andThen(second);
}
```

So you could use:

```
.sorted(comparing( FuncUtils.compose(Job::getJob, Enum::name)))
```

Comment: _Unfortunately there is no "clean" way to achieve the result, because to call a default method on a method reference you need to assign it, or cast it._ -- Not really true. Use _type witness_: `Comparator.<JobRsp, Job>comparing(...)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: What i meant is that you can't call:  `(Job::getJob).andThen(Enum::name)`

Comment: Okay, I missed _that_ point being confused for chaining comparators, and not function composition that can be implemented with a lambda expression. Anyway, there is another clean way omitting the cast and even introducing an intermediate typed variable by `static <T, R> Function<T, R> f(final Function<T, R> f) { return f; }` and `f(ObjA::getObjB).andThen(ObjB::getObjC).andThen(ObjC::getObjD).andThen(ObjD::getObjE)`. I don't see a reason of having the `compose` method then.